# Substitution of variable in a second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to make a substitution of a new variable into a second order differential equation. However, I am not sure how to do this, I have seen examples online but they do not seem to be applicable to my case. I would like to know the procedure followed in order to have my original equation be written in terms of t instead of r.

Here is the equation: [image]

This is the new variable I would like the equation to be in terms of: [image]

Comment: Have you tried calculating dr in terms of t and just plugging that in for you equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new variable is just:
$$t=Cr^2$$
Now we have:
$$\dfrac {dR}{dr}=\dfrac {dR}{dt} \dfrac {dt}{dr}=2Cr\dfrac {dR}{dt}$$
$$\implies \dfrac 2r\dfrac {dR}{dr}=4C\dfrac {dR}{dt}$$
Where $C$ is a constant. Do the same for $\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}$

---

For $\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}$
$$\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}=\dfrac {dR'}{dr}=\dfrac {d}{dr}\left (2Cr\dfrac {dR}{dt}\right)$$
$$\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}=2C\left (\dfrac {dR}{dt}\right)+2Cr\dfrac {d}{dr}\left (\dfrac {dR}{dt}\right)$$
$$\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}=2C\left (\dfrac {dR}{dt}\right)+2Cr\left (\dfrac {d^2R}{dt^2}\right)\dfrac {dt}{dr}$$
$$\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}=2C\left (\dfrac {dR}{dt}\right)+4C^2r^2\left (\dfrac {d^2R}{dt^2}\right)$$
Finally:
$$\dfrac {d^2R}{dr^2}=2C\dfrac {dR}{dt}+4Ct\dfrac {d^2R}{dt^2}$$

Comment: I have trouble doing the second derivative this way. Can you help out?

Comment: I added some lines @Σbaryon

Comment: Im not sure how to express R prime

Comment: Is it more clear now ? @Σbaryon

Comment: yep thanks for the help :)

Comment: You are very welcome @Σbaryon